# HTML 5 in native iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, html, native, linkedin-api

LinkedIn used HTML 5 for their iOS Universal app. I have built a few iPhone apps but with Objective-C. I also want to build an native app that uses HTML 5. IS there any good resource to learn about that from scratch?

Did they used UIWebView whenever they needed to embed HTML 5 in their app? Please help

Answer (score -1):

Try out [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/):

> honeGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app stores. PhoneGap leverages web technologies developers already know best... HTML and JavaScript.

and the easy [Tutorials](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials)

Comment: But I am very sure Linkedin guys did not use PhoneGAP. The did it using UIWebView only.

Comment: But if someone is already familiar with iOS coding, using PhoneGap is pointless.

Comment: nope, i saves a mass of time for your project! Take a look at: http://phonegap.com/about/features